# ScriptIntrinsicBlur produces black bitmaps

Tags: android, renderscript

I am trying to blur bitmaps in my app using RenderScript framework. I am using the following code:

```
public static Bitmap apply(Context context, Bitmap sentBitmap, int radius)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);

    final RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
    final Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, sentBitmap,
                                                         Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
                                                         Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    final Allocation output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());
    final ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    script.setRadius(radius);
    script.setInput(input);
    script.forEach(output);
    output.copyTo(bitmap);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Unfortunately all I get with the code is black bitmaps. How can I fix the issue?

Bitmaps passed to the `apply` method are created in the following way:

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(thisView.getWidth(),
                               thisView.getHeight(),
                               Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

The width and height of these bitmaps are multiples of 4.

There are also some errors reported by RenderScript but I don't know what they means and how should I fix them (the documentation for `ScriptIntrinsicBlur` is rather thin). Here are these errors:

```
20305-20391/com.xxx E/RenderScript﹕ rsi_ScriptIntrinsicCreate 5
20305-20391/com.xxx E/RenderScript﹕ rsAssert failed: mUserRefCount > 0, in 
frameworks/rs/rsObjectBase.cpp at 112
```

EDIT:

The radius is 5 and I am running the app on Samsung Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.2.1.

Comment: What is `radius` set to in your runs?  What version of Android?  Looking at the rsObjectBase.cpp code, the logs an assertions aren't in the 4.3.1 or 4.4.2 sources.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer I have updated my question. Could you please have a look?

Comment: are you using the support library? you should be using the support library.

Comment: @TimMurray, he's running 4.2.1 which is API 17 and ScriptIntrinsics were introduced in API 17.  Is there something specific he needs from the support lib?

Comment: support lib fixes this exact issue, for one. also the performance for blur in particular is identical and will run on things that don't have 4.2+.

Comment: Thanks, Tim, appreciate the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Tim Murray, I fixed the issue (there were two actually)

I switched to using the support library and now I hope Android Studio with gradle projects will eventually learn to handle the library symbols.

Another major source of problems was the fact I used completely transparent bitmaps as input for the `ScriptIntrinsicBlur`. My bad.

**EDIT from March-07-2013**

Android Studio 0.5 fixes issues with support RenderScript in Gradle-powered projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to blur your input bitmap image:

```
Bitmap BlurImage(Bitmap input) {
            RenderScript rsScript = RenderScript.create(this);
            Allocation alloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rsScript, input);

            ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rsScript, alloc.getElement());
            blur.setRadius(12);
            blur.setInput(alloc);

            Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight(), input.getConfig());
            Allocation outAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rsScript, result);
            blur.forEach(outAlloc);
            outAlloc.copyTo(result);

            rsScript.destroy();
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: I tried the above code and unfortunately it throws `android.renderscript.RSIllegalArgumentException: Unsuported element type`.

Comment: Strange becouse I test this function and for me was ok, please be sure that you pass the correct bitmap and try to clean your project before running again

Comment: That's occurring because `ScriptIntrinsicBlur` only allows an `Element` of `U8_4`.  I suspect what is happening with your original blur code is the result of the `createFromBitmap` is giving you an `Allocation` with `Element.RGBA_8888` which is not the same thing (confusing, right?)

Comment: Yes that's the problem. You can try without make it Element.RGBA_8888.

Comment: Can we use this to image loader